# How to get public key of an access token from an identity provider (ex. Google)

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

In oauth2, to validate the access token by the resource server, the public key is normally required?
Google, for example google, I looked in https://console.developers.google.com/ but couldn't find it.

Comment: Go to credential tab and there you can create key after registering your app.

Comment: Sorry,i didn't understand, i 'm looking for the public key to validate the access token. Normally google app uses a private key to generate the access token and provide a public key to validate the token.

Comment: See the below link  https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#create_a_client_id_and_client_secret